# Топить и... топить

Tags: этимология, омонимы

Почему одним словом называют и погружение предмета в воду до "невсплытия", и загруз в печь топлива — топить? Разные же совершенно вещи.

Comment: Отвечаю просто из принципа. Потому, что это не одно слово, а два разных слова.
Вас не удивляет, что одним словом "коса" называют как минимум три разные вещи?
Или лук, нос, лавка?
Такие слова называются [омонимами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC).

Comment: Есть ещё старое выражение «утопить очи», т.е. уставить (ся).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ТОПИТЬ 1** «заставлять тонуть». Общеслав. Обозначает понудительное действие (каузатив) глаг. тонуть. Образовано, вероятно, от сущ. *tорь > топь «болото, топкое место» неясного происхождения. От глаг.* topiti «погружать в воду или во что-либо топкое» произведен с суф. -nọ- > -ну- глаг. *topnọti > после упрощения пн- > н соврем.* тонуть* «опускаться 
на дно», «увязать в чем-то». (Цыганенко)

**ТОПИТЬ 2** «отапливать». Общеслав. Имеет соответствия в других и.-е. языках. Соврем. слово развилось из др.-рус. *топити* «жечь что-либо в печи для нагревания» вследствие утраты конечного безударного -и (в укр. топити — тожд. -и сохраняется). С XVIII в. у слова *топить* фиксируется также знач. «нагревая, делать жидким», «плавить». Др.-рус. *топити* восходит к праслав. *topiti «нагревать», букв. «заставлять быть теплым» (ср. 
ст.-сл. топлъ «теплый»). Это понудительная форма (каузатив) к утрач. глаг.* tepti (чередов. е//о в корне слова). Прич. с суф. -л- данного глаг. *teplъ дало др.-рус. прил.* теплый *> с переходом е > ё соврем.* тёплый *«содержащий умеренное количество тепла» (в укр. теплий — тожд. е сохраняется). Форма ср. р. прил.* тепло *дала сущ.* тепло *теплота» (субстантивация); с суф. -от-а (как красота) — теплота «тепло», нареч. тепло 
«не холодно». Ему родственны: др.-инд. tapati «греет», taptas «теплый», лат. tepidus «теплый, тепловатый». От глаг. топити «отапливать» с пом. суф. -ък-а образовано сущ. топъка > после утраты ъ --*топка *«действие топить», «место, где сжигают топливо»; с суф. -j-ь с изменением п- > пл— сущ.* топль *«теплота» (отмечается в памятниках XV в.). От* топль *с пом. суф. -ив-о (как* огниво*) произведено сущ.* топливо* «то, что используется для получения тепла», известное в вост.-слав, языках. (Цыганенко)

Слова имеют разное происхождение, следовательно, не являются родственными ни в диахронии, ни в синхронии.

Comment: Что самое смешное, абсолютно исчерпывающий и интресный сам по себе ответ формально не соответствует вопросу. Автор спрашивает "Почему называют одним словом?", а не то, родственны ли слова.   
Напоминает историю про заблудившихся на воздушном шаре Холмса и Ватсона, заметивших внизу пастуха. 
- Сэр, вы не подскажете, где мы находимся?
- Вы находитесь на воздушном шаре в сорока футах от земли. Сэр!
- Спасибо, сэр! Мы в России, Ватсон.
...
(окончание см. инете, кто не знает)